# window.scrollTo() breaking with Polymer Project core-scroll-header-panel

Tags: javascript, scroll, polymer, core-scroll-header-panel

I'm using the Polymer project and am stuck trying to scroll to elements on the page using javascript.

I'm trying to call `window.scrollTo(x,y)` on a page that uses `core-scroll-header-panel` but just get `undefined` when trying to do this.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ucbhUP9F5j2h6meDReR?p=preview) that shows the problem in action. Hit the CLICK ME link to attempt to scroll to 100,0. You will see that this doesn't happen.

If you comment out the `<core-scroll-header-panel>` lines then you will see that clicking the same link will scroll you down the page. Here is the relevant [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHB7akEgo7Y7BVk4t2nW?p=preview).

I know that I can use `document.getElementById('some-element').scrollIntoView()` but this doesn't help me achieve what I want to achieve, which is animated scrolling down the page to the element. I also know that `window.scrollTo()` will not be animated, but I can use that call to make my own animated scroll method.

Any ideas around why this is happening, and how I can fix this to get the desired behaviour? jQuery is not an option.

Comment: It is not working because you don't have to scroll on the window but on the shadow-dom element that contains the contents. Just go down the tree to find the proper element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was what Andreas mentioned in his comment.

The scroll isn't bound to the window, but is bound to a component in the shadow dom.

In this particular instance the `window.scrollTo` call needs to be replaced with this:

`document.querySelector('core-scroll-header-panel').scroller.scrollTop = 100;`

Here is the relevant [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EZCAMIpGFRvd5tkIJdaX?p=preview).